# Custom imputer does not work with to.numpy ()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, object, scikit-learn

I'm creating a custom imputer that receives a field and fills the null values ​​with the average grouped by the field.
The code below works, but when trying to return the object transforming it into a numpy array, I get the array, but I don't change the data frame, which has its missing values ​​replaced, but remains a data frame.
I would like an array because I want to create a pipeline and use this function.

```
class ImputerPersonalizado(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self,baseado_em_campo=None,to_nump=False):
    self.baseado_em_campo=baseado_em_campo
    self.to_nump=to_nump
def fit(self,X,y=None):
    if self.baseado_em_campo==None:
        pass
    else:
        self.imputar_=X.groupby(by=self.baseado_em_campo).mean()
    return self
def transform(self,X,y=None):
    if self.baseado_em_campo==None:
        if self.to_nump:
            X.fillna(X.mean(),inplace=True)
            return X.to_numpy()
        else:
            return X.fillna(X.mean(),inplace=True)
    else:
        X.set_index([self.baseado_em_campo],inplace=True)
        for c in X:
            try:
                X[c]=X[c].fillna(self.imputar_[c])
            except:
                pass
        if self.to_nump:
            X.reset_index(inplace=True)
            return X.to_numpy()
        else:
            return X.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
train_test=pd.DataFrame({'Pclass': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1},
 'PassengerId': {0: 6, 1: 18, 2: 21, 3: 23, 4: 24},
 'Survived': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'Name': {0: 'Moran, Mr. James',
  1: 'Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene',
  2: 'Fynney, Mr. Joseph J',
  3: 'McGowan, Miss. Anna "Annie"',
  4: 'Sloper, Mr. William Thompson'},
 'Sex': {0: 'male', 1: 'male', 2: 'male', 3: 'female', 4: 'male'},
 'Age': {0: 15.0, 1: 35.0, 2: 35.0, 3: 15.0, 4: 28.0},
 'SibSp': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Parch': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Ticket': {0: '330877', 1: '244373', 2: '239865', 3: '330923', 4: '113788'},
 'Fare': {0: 8.4583, 1: 13.0, 2: 26.0, 3: 8.0292, 4: 35.5},
 'Cabin': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 'A6'},
 'Embarked': {0: 'Q', 1: 'S', 2: 'S', 3: 'Q', 4: 'S'}})
```

Then, when i run:

```
imput=ImputerPersonalizado(baseado_em_campo='Pclass',to_nump=True)
imput.fit_transform(train_test)
```

I get an array as return, but when I look ate the train_test it is still a data frame.

I know I could just turn it into numpy array aftewards, but I'd like to understand why i can't return the data frame as array.

imports used:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: `return X.reset_index(inplace=True)` returns `None`, not your data

Comment: also, you don't capture the output. python passes values, not references

Comment: can you make this a runnable example so that I can tinker with it (in other words, include all of the imports needed)

Comment: Done! is there anything else I can include that helps?